# Passing array reference to function PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I'm fairly new to PHP. I'm trying to filter out an array of items that contain a specific string. In order to then push those items to array, I need to pass the array to the function as a reference (or so my research has told me) however I can't seem to get it to work, any ideas? Thanks all.

```
$filteredS3Results = array();

function filterResults($var, &$filteredS3Results) {
    
if (strpos($var, '008-20160916') !== false) {
      array_push($filteredS3Results, $var);
   };
};

array_filter($s3Results,"filterResults");
```

Comment: That's not how `array_filter` works. The callback function is supposed to return true or false, then `array_filter` returns the new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function just receives one argument, the array element being tested. It should return a boolean value that indicates whether the element should be included in the filtered result.

```
$filteredS3Results = array_filter($s3Results, "filterResults");

function filterResults($var) {
    return strpos($var, '008-21060916') !== false;
}
```